# It can't display a toast in a application , and others is ok

Tags: android, toast

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(PhotoListActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LogUtils.printDebug("123", "ok");
    }
});
```

The log `LogUtils.printDebug("123", "ok")` works but the `Toast` isn't displayed.

Comment: Watch your formatting please...

Comment: As toast is showing but display time is short

Comment: Try This ..............Toast.makeText(PhotoListActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I  try  but it still cann't display.

Answer (score 1):

try change `PhotoListActivity.this` to `getAplicationContext()`

Comment: what difference it will make?

Comment: I try it , but doesn't.  and  other applictions is ok.

Comment: can you post your full script i will check it

Answer (score 0):

Either try this ..
`PhotoListActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {`
`@Override`
 `.....`
`});`

Or use this .. 
`getAplicationContext()` instead of `PhotoListActivity.this` in `makeText()`

Answer (score 0):

Try This. As only problem is that you have given Toast Short time

```
Toast.makeText(PhotoListActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Is the  toast  closed in  an application  so that it cann't  popup?